# Trying to use `rejectUnauthorized:false` for node 18 fetch does not work

Tags: node.js, ssl, fetch

I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061143/using-rejectunauthorized-with-node-fetch-in-node-js) but found that it does not work in my script

For context, I am just testing TLS configurations for my server. I understand that `rejectUnauthorized: false` is an insecure practice but for development purposes I've created my own certs.

Here's my code:

```js
const https = require('https');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

const url = 'https://myoauthendpoint/oauthProtected';
const options = {
  agent: httpsAgent,
  method: 'GET',
};

const start = async () => {
  console.log('starting fetch');
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log({ data });
    }
    console.log({ response });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
  }
};

start();
```

When I run this code, I get this error

```
{
  err: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11413:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async start (/Users/danielchicchon/Projects/testing/misc/fetch/start.js:19:22) {
    cause: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
        at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) {
      code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are your certificate options for that https server? Since it's https, not http, you still need to tell Node where to find your key and cert files (see the Node docs over on https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequestoptions-callback, second example, which creates an agent)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans even when I do pass in my key and cert files I still receive the same `self_signed_cert` error

Comment: And you of course already tried the various things mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990 ?

Comment: I haven't tried those since I'm looking for a script based solution rather than an environment solution. I've found several workarounds that I'll post below

Comment: This answer helped my solve my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946885/accept-self-signed-certificates-for-undici-fetch